# Make a given number by adding given numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, mathematics

I have created a code that checks if a number can be made by adding different quantities of given numbers and if so returns the quantities. Is this the best way to do this or is there a more efficient way?

Here is my function:

```
def sumFinder(quantities, final_num):
    if len(quantities) == 1:
        for i in range(final_num//quantities[0]+1):
            num = quantities[0] * i
            if num == final_num:
                return [i]
        return False
    for i in range(final_num//quantities[0]+1):
        num = quantities[0]*i
        found_nums = sumFinder(quantities[1:], final_num-num)
        if found_nums:
            return [i] + found_nums
    return False
```

This is an example of it working:

```
for num in range(100):
    answer = sumFinder([4, 6, 9, 20], num)
    if answer:
        a, b, c, d = answer
        answer = "4({}) + 6({}) + 9({}) + 20({})".format(a, b, c, d)
    print(num, "=", answer)
```

Comment: You should make it clear that you are looking for positive integral multipliers on integers. Otherwise, for any 2 co-prime numbers, `a` and `b`, you can always find `m` and `n` such that `a*m + b*n = c` for all possible integer `c`

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? @hjpotter92

Comment: For eg. 4 and 9 are co primes, and you can generate: `4*-2 + 9*1 = 1`, `4*-4 + 9*2 = 2` and so on. For all other values, the coefficients can be `0`. So there should be some other contraints.

Comment: That is a good point @hjpotter92. How do you propose that I implement these constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avoid repeated values**

In your testing code, the values `4, 6, 9, 20` appear in multiple places. You could re-write your code to generate a formatted answer from the list:

```
num_list = [4, 6, 9, 20]
for num in range(100):
    answer = sumFinder(num_list, num)
    if answer:
        answer = " + ".join("{} * {}".format(a, b) for a, b in zip(num_list, answer))
    print(num, "=", answer)
```

**Document your function and use the correct type**

Your function returns both lists and boolean. Maybe it's be clearer to make it return a list (when a list is found) and `None` otherwise. This can be documented accordingly in a docstring.

```
def sumFinder(quantities, final_num):
    """Return a list such that dot-product(list, quantities) == final_num. Return None when no list is found."""
    if len(quantities) == 1:
        for i in range(final_num//quantities[0]+1):
            num = quantities[0] * i
            if num == final_num:
                return [i]
        return None
    for i in range(final_num//quantities[0]+1):
        num = quantities[0]*i
        found_nums = sumFinder(quantities[1:], final_num-num)
        if found_nums:
            return [i] + found_nums
    return None
```

**Handle empty input**

You access the first element of the input without checking the length first. Maybe it'd be clearer to document this as an invalid input or you could handle it properly by returning `[] if final_sum == 0 else None`.

**Removing duplicated logic**

When the empty case is handled, the case with 1 element doesn't need to be handled in a special way.

With a few minor changes, you can write:

```
def sumFinder(quantities, final_num):
    """Return a list such that dot-product(list, quantities) == final_num. Return None when no list is found."""
    if not quantities:
        return [] if final_num == 0 else None
    first, remain = quantities[0], quantities[1:]
    for i in range(final_num//first+1):
        found_nums = sumFinder(remain, final_num - first * i)
        if found_nums is not None:
            return [i] + found_nums
    return None
```

**Names**

Python names are usually `snake_cased`. Also, `find_sum` would be a better name that `sum_finder` which sounds like a class name.

`final_num` could be renamed `target`, `n`, etc.

`quantities` could be renamed `lst`